# Not compiling anymore after minor windows update

Tags: windows, texworks, update

So from one day to the other texworks on windows 10 won't compile anymore. I didn't change anything in the document, it used to compile fine. 
The only thing that I did was run an anti-malware program since I had some annoying malware. In the course of the removal, windows apparantly updated, at least it said so during restarting. The software was roguekiller.

Now I can't compile anymore.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=Matchlowercase}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}
\setsansfont{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

and this is the error I get: 
[image]

Comment: You used TeXWorks? Can the document be compiled via command line? That will help identify whether the problem is with TeXWorks, or the eX system.

Comment: I get the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the options. It should be `Scale=MatchLowercase` not `Scale=Matchlowercase`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}
%\setsansfont{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It compiles again. Really strange as so far this hasn't been a problem. Thanks again =)